# IText merge tagged pdf - Rebuild failed: trailer not found.; Original message: PDF startxref not found

Tags: itext

We use `iText` version 5.5 `PdfCopy` to merge multiple tagged PDFs. (Those tagged PDFs are not created by `iText`.)  We  got the following error while `document.close`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RefKey.<init>(RefKey.java:59)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.fixTaggedStructure(PdfCopy.java:822)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.flushTaggedObjects(PdfCopy.java:779)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:854)
at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:416)
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Rebuild failed: trailer not found.;    Original    message: PDF startxref not found.
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:668)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:181)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:230)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:207)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
```

PDF are valid and contains trailer and `%EOF`, Files are not corrupted. What other could cause this?

Comment: Maybe one of the PDFs you're trying to merge isn't tagged or isn't tagged correctly. In any case: answering this question isn't possible without an example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 16):

You may have found the answer already. I had the same issue and I solved it by closing the document before instantiating PdfReader.

Example:

**

```
Document tempDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 80, 20);
ByteArrayOutputStream tempBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
PdfWriter.getInstance(tempDoc, tempBaos);
tempDoc.open();

tempDoc.add(tempChap);
tempDoc.close();    // Closing the document before calling Reader

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempBaos.toByteArray());
```

**

Hope this will help

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks a lot for sharing